# Eclipse CDT can't index any QT header file

Tags: indexing, qt5, eclipse-cdt

as you can see as below image:
[image: capture of CDT]

The QT includes have been added correctly
But all QT header files didn't indexed correctly,and other 3rdparty lib header file like vtk can be indexed correctly.

How can I fix this issue?

My configuration

```
OS     : Ubuntu 22.04
Eclipse: 2023-06 (4.28.0)
CDT    : 11.2.0.202303140100
QT     : 5.15.2
GC     : 11.4.0
```